# LSTMで転倒検知の精度を出力する際、エラーは出ないが結果が矛盾している。コードのどこかに不具合があると考えられるが原因を突き止めることが出来ない。どの部分を修正すべき？？

Tags: python

転倒、非転倒、静止、それぞれ左右前後の動作と歩行の13種類の動作を格納したデータを半分に分割しモデルを構築しました。その後、歩行→転倒・非転倒→静止の流れの動作をスライドウィンドウ方式で分割した新しいテストデータでテストした際、本来静止になる最後の部分が転倒のラベルが80％ほどの確率で出力されてしまいます。同じ学習データとテストデータをk-shape法で行った際はそのような異常はなく、問題はコードにあると考えております。以下がそれらのコードです。

※
1.学習データの一列目はラベル、2列目以降はデータとなっている。
2.モデルの評価は以下の通りである。
Test Loss: 0.3621090054512024
Test Accuracy: 0.9275000095367432

```
# データの読み込み
data = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/kenkyu/kshape_data/" + file_name + "/" + data_name + ".csv", delimiter=",")
data.dropna(inplace=True)

# トレーニングデータとテストデータに分割
data_train, data_test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.5, random_state=2000)

# 特徴量とラベルの分離
X_train = data_train.iloc[:, 1:].values
y_train = data_train.iloc[:, 0].values
X_test = data_test.iloc[:, 1:].values
y_test = data_test.iloc[:, 0].values

# データの形状変更 (サンプル数, 時系列の長さ, 特徴量数)
X_train_reshaped = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 231, 1))  # 時系列の長さを 231 に設定
X_test_reshaped = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], 231, 1))  # 時系列の長さを 231 に設定

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Bidirectional

# モデルの構築
model = Sequential()

# 畳み込み層を追加
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(231, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

# 双方向LSTM層を追加
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100)))

# ドロップアウト層を追加
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

# 出力層
model.add(Dense(13, activation='softmax'))

# モデルのコンパイル
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# モデルのトレーニング
history = model.fit(X_train_reshaped, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

#予測結果の格納用の辞書を初期化
results_file1 = {}

for j in range(int(num), int(amount) + 1):
    results_file1[f"{file1}{j}"] = []

    for i in range(1, int(max_i) + 1):
        print(i)
        # ファイルパスの構築
        file_path1 = f'/content/drive/MyDrive/kenkyu/kshape_data/test_data/ファイル分け後2/{file1}{j}/{file1}{j}_acc_{i}.csv'

        # データのロード
        test_data = np.genfromtxt(file_path1, delimiter=',')

        # データのリシェイプ (231,) -> (1, 231, 1)
        test_data_reshaped = test_data.reshape((1, 231, 1))

        # 予測の実行
        probabilities = model.predict(test_data_reshaped)[0]
        predicted_class = np.argmax(probabilities)

        # 各カテゴリの計算
        tento = probabilities[0] + probabilities[2] + probabilities[4] + probabilities[6]
        nottento = probabilities[1] + probabilities[3] + probabilities[5] + probabilities[7]
        walking = probabilities[8]
        staying = probabilities[9] + probabilities[10] + probabilities[11] + probabilities[12]

        # 合計で割ってパーセンテージに変換
        total = tento + nottento + walking + staying
        tento_percentage = (tento / total) * 100
        nottento_percentage = (nottento / total) * 100
        walking_percentage = (walking / total) * 100
        staying_percentage = (staying / total) * 100

        # 予測結果をリストに追加
        results_file1[f"{file1}{j}"].append([
            predicted_class, tento_percentage, nottento_percentage, walking_percentage, staying_percentage, *[p * 100 for p in probabilities]
        ])

    # 予測結果をDataFrameに変換しCSV出力
    columns = [
        'label', 'tento', 'nottento', 'walking', 'staying', 'detail_0', 'detail_1', 'detail_2', 'detail_3', 'detail_4', 'detail_5', 'detail_6', 'detail_7', 'detail_8', 'detail_9', 'detail_10', 'detail_11', 'detail_12'
    ]
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(results_file1[f"{file1}{j}"], columns=columns)
    temp_df.to_csv(f'/content/drive/MyDrive/kenkyu/kshape_data/test_data/result LSTM(nozato×nozato)/{file1}{j}_acc.csv', index=True)
```